# Proving a set is linearly ordered set given relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let fin(N) be the set of all finite subsets of the natural numbers.

I was asked to show that under the relation <=, fin(N) is partially ordered set, where A<=B means either A=B, or that max(A symmetric difference B) is a member of B.

I find it hard to prove that this relation is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A\le B\le C$. We need to prove that $A\le C$. Suppose this was not the case, $A\not\le C$. This implies $A\not= C$, hence the symmetric difference $A\Delta C$ is non empty, and $\max(A\Delta C)=a\in A$. (For any $P,Q$ either $P=Q$ or $P<Q$, or $Q<P$, indeed if $P\not= Q$, then either $\max(P\Delta Q)\in P$ so $Q<P$, or $\max(P\Delta Q)\in Q$ in which case $P<Q$.) Also, $A\not = B$ and $B\not= C$, hence $\max(A\Delta B)=b\in B$ and $\max(B\Delta C)=c\in C$. 
Note that $a\not\in C$, $b\not\in A$, and $c\not\in B$.

We will derive a contradiction, from which we will conclude that the assumption $A\not\le C$ was wrong. We could have cases as follows: either $a\in B$ or $a\not\in B$; either $c\in A$ or $c\not\in A$; either $b\in C$ or $b\not\in C$. This makes $2\times2\times2=8$ cases total to consider, in each we will derive a contradiction.

Case $a\in B$, $c\in A$, $b\in C$. Since $b\in C\setminus A$, $b<a$. Since $c\in A\setminus B$, $c<b$. Since $a\in B\setminus C$, $a<c$. Thus $a<c<b<a$, a contradiction.

The remaining cases are treated in a similar way (a Venn diagram would help, but we will just list them without a diagram).

Case $a\in B$, $c\in A$, $b\not\in C$. Since $b\in B\setminus C$, $b<c$. 
Since $c\in A\setminus B$, $c<b$, a contradiction.
This also applies to the Case $a\not\in B$, $c\in A$, $b\not\in C$.

Case $a\in B$, $c\not\in A$, $b\in C$. Then $a<c<a$, a contradiction.
Also applies to the Case $a\in B$, $c\not\in A$, $b\not\in C$.

Case $a\not\in B$, $c\in A$, $b\in C$. Then $a<b<a$, a contradiction.
Also applies to the Case $a\not\in B$, $c\not\in A$, $b\in C$.

Case $a\not\in B$, $c\not\in A$, $b\not\in C$. Then $a<b$, $c<a$, $b<c$, 
so $a<b<c<a$, a contradiction.